# How to split polygons in one layer into polygons of a different layer in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: polygon, layers, overlapping-features

I am using ArcGIS Pro and I have 2 layers that are both polygons. The first layer is called ELC, and the second layer is called SPU. My ELC polygons overlap my SPU polygons, sometimes the ELC layer overlaps multiple SPU polygons. I want to split my ELC polygons into the SPU polygon they overlap with. The reason I want to do this is so that I can get the total area of ELC polygons within each SPU polygon. I have tried using the split tool but it gives me errors when I try to do this for multiple polygons. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You want either a Union or an Intersect.

Comment: Do any ELC polygons overlap other ELC polygons? Do any SPU polygons overlap other SPU polygons?

Comment: the ELC polygons don't overlap each other, but 1 ELC polygon is sometimes within multiple SPU polygons. And SPU polygons don't overlap but most of them are right next to each other.

Comment: I looked up union, but it looks like you lose the boundary for ELC if I use union, and I want to maintain all the boundaries of the polygons.